# How to limit the max values per key in Hadoop?

Tags: configuration, hadoop, mapreduce

this is my problem. 
I have a large data set to work with, and I need to limit the max values per key. Sometimes I have 10000+ values per key and that's more that I need.

So how can I configure my job to get just 'x' values per key? (any key) after reduce phase.

EDIT: This is the reduce source code. My main problem is that sometimes I get an OutOfMemory, and it's because the StringBuilder gets huge.

Maybe there is a way to say, "I just want 10.000 values per key" through configuration. If not, I have to put some extra code in my reducer ...

```
public void reduce(Text domain, Iterable<Text> inLinks, Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        allInlinks = new StringBuilder();

        for (Text text : inLinks) {

                allInlinks.append(text.toString());
                allInlinks.append(",");               
        }

        allLinksText.set(allInlinks.toString());

        context.write(domain, allLinksText);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce size of the reducer output?

Comment: The idea is to limit the output related to the key values count not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused as the records output from the reduce phase are in the form (K,V), not (K, {V,V,V}). Now, the records output from the Map phase are in the form (K, {V,V,V}) and it's up to the reducer to condense these intermediate values however it sees fit. If you're running your own Java based MapReduce jobs, you can attempt to limit the number of records output from each phase via code, but this doesn't exactly fit the bigdata paradigm. Some more clarification about your data/current solution/desired output is necessary.

Comment: @psabbate is it possible that you may have multiple duplicate inLinks in your output string? If so, this may be one way to reduce the size of the output string. Another method I can think of involves associating some sort of metric with your inLinks, then only appending those inLinks to your output string that are above/below the metric.

Answer (score 1):

Does something simple like this not work? Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question.

```
reduce(Key key, Iterator<Value> values) {
    int count = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        if (count < x) {
            // do whatever
            count++;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, there is some "waste" in that all of the values for each key are still sorted and copied to reducers, but I don't really see a way around that. You could do a similar thing in a Combiner and have it only output up to x for each key, but depending on your distribution of keys/mappers, that's only a little bit helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to do that, maybe there is a way to accomplish this through configuration.

Comment: Sorry, there's no way I know of to do it through configuration. Typically configuration is used to control parts of the process that you can't inject custom code into. For example, the shuffle/sort phase, or Mapper/Reducer allocation. Since you can easily add whatever logic you want to the reducer, there's not much in terms of provided configuration options there.